# Set the size of a dynamic column via code behind- JQGRID

Tags: c#, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a JQGrid that dynamically creates columns, and get all the records in a datatable. How can I set the size of each column depends how long the characters on the rows are? Or if the characters on the row is too short and the header text is longer, the size of the column depends on the characters of header.

i.e.

```
Name      |Age|Contact Number|
John Smith|6  |12345         |
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of each column manually to be fixed using the `width` property  or can resize the column size depending on header using `resizeToTitleWidth`

```
var colModelData = [
    {name:'Name', index:'Name', width:55},
    {name:'Age', index:'Age', resizeToTitleWidth:true},
    {name:'ContactNumber', index:'ContactNumber', resizeToTitleWidth:true}];
```

Also try using `autowidth: true`

[Source](http://www.dorffweb.com/wordpress/2010/04/setting-jqgrid-column-width-from-titles/)